# Since we changed the value of int to 10 inside the if, why do i get 33 printed after the second fork for both child and the child it created?

Tags: c, if-statement, variables, integer, fork

here is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[ ]){
    int x = 33;
    if(!fork()){
        int x = 10;
        printf("%d\n", x);
    }
    fork();
    printf("%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

i would assume that because the value of int changes for the original child, it carries the value of 10 and in the second fork as well(fork();), so the original child and its child print 10 so the output is like this: 33 33 10 10 10
But it seems that although the value of int changes inside the if, the child then gets back the original value of x which is 33 and both print 33 after the second fork(so the output is like this: 33 33 10 33 33. Why is that?(i believe \n doesnt have anything to do with it) [here is a photo of what i think is happening but apparently it doesnt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYQPd.jpg)

Comment: The value of `x` doesn't change, you just have two different variables with the same name. Try calling of them `y`.

Comment: Or change `int x = 10;` to just `x = 10;`. Then it's assigning the same variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `x` printed in the first `printf` inside the `if` block is defined with a local scope that ends at the `}`. The second `printf` uses the `x` defined in the scope of the `main` body that still has the initial value `33`.

Redefining a variable in a local scope with the same name as one define in an enclosing scope is called *shadowing*. It is confusing and error prone and will be reported with a warning if you enable advanced compiler warnings with `-Wall -Wextra` or `-Weverything`.

Here is a modified version that should produce output closer to your expectations:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int x = 33;
    if (!fork()) {
        x = 10;
        printf("%d\n", x);
    }
    fork();
    printf("%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

This version should print `33` twice and `10` three times in an unpredictable order.

The original version posted in the question should print `33` 4 times and `10` just once in an unpredictable order.

Comment: thank you very much. this is an exam question not my program. so as soon as the if ends the child goes back to its original value of 33 right?

Comment: @MikeBalts: not the child, the variable `x` defined in the scope of the `if` block disappears.  The `x` used in the second `printf` is a **different** variable, defined at the top of the `main()` body as `int x = 33;` and never changed in any of the processes.

Comment: @0___________: it should print `33` twice and `10` 4 times  in an unpredictable order.

Comment: oh so the x inside the if is another variable, with the same character in order to confuse. i see. so its like having an x in main and then a y inside the if right?

Comment: @MikeBalts: exactly! very confusing indeed.

Comment: @MikeBalts and fork makes it even more confusing

Comment: this professors in this class man :'D haha. thank you so much youve been really helpful. i think the correct output is: 33 33 10 33 33(in random order obv)

Comment: @0___________: so confusing! the OP's version should print `33` 4 times and `10` just once in an unpredictable order and my version should print `33` twice and `10` 3 times  in an unpredictable order. I don't understand how Godbolt collects the output of multiple processes. Running again produces different results.

Comment: if you use linux or wsl:ubuntu in vscode the output should be 33 -> 4 times and 10->one time. since there are 4 processes after the second fork(two from the original parent and two from the original child themselves included) that all print 33.

Comment: Yes, I did not use fork for ages.

Comment: @0___________: the Godbolt output is intriguing! I think you found a bug.

Comment: Godbolt is sketchy. one last question. in the example you provided basically we are doing the opposite, changing the value of x for the original child process which proceeds to pass to its child as well, after the second fork, so child changes x to 10, prints it, exits if, creates child, both print 10. Leaving the parent with the original value of x(33) which he and his child will print? 33 two times 10 three times

Comment: @MikeBalts: yes.

Comment: you ve been extremely helpful indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You define two `x`s in two different scopes. One is inside the `if` and it stops to exist when the program exits that scope.

But it will still print `33` only :)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[ ])
{
  int x = 33;
  if(fork())
  {
     x = 10;
     printf("%d\n", x);
  }
  fork();
  printf("%d\n", x);
  return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/PWvGcq5qM

I think you want too see this result :)

Comment: Godbolt limits your ability to call fork() (to prevent fork-bombs from upsetting/crashing the server).  Not sure exactly what the policy is that causes that output, though.